# Ajuda com SQL e PHP

Tags: php, email

Boa tarde, eu preciso de uma ajuda, sou iniciante no php

tenho o seguinte código que funciona e envia o e-mail tudo certo.

```html
<?php

$host    = "mysql:dbname=agendamentos;host=phpmyadmin.srv-45-34-12-242.hostoo.io";
$usuario = "agendamento";
$pass    = "#####";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($host, $usuario, $pass);
}catch (PDOExecption $e){
    echo "Falha: ". $e->getMessage();
}

$email    = "victor@diferencialcontabil.cnt.br";
$assunto  = "Email Teste";
$mensagem = "teste de email enviado com php e sql";
$header   = "from: victor teste";

mail($email, $assunto, $mensagem, $header);

?>
```

Mas, quando tento colocar alguma variavel para buscal no banco de dados eu não consigo ele para de enviar os e-mails, segue o jeito que estou tentando fazer.

```html
<?php

$host    = "mysql:dbname=agendamentos;host=phpmyadmin.srv-45-34-12-242.hostoo.io";
$usuario = "agendamento";
$pass    = "####";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($host, $usuario, $pass);
}catch (PDOExecption $e){
    echo "Falha: ". $e->getMessage();
}

$buscaemail="select email from clientes where id=103";

$email    = "$buscaemail";
$assunto  = "Email Teste";
$mensagem = "teste de email enviado com php e sql";
$header   = "from: victor teste";

mail($email, $assunto, $mensagem, $header);

?>
```

Desde já agradeço muito, grato!

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$host    = "mysql:dbname=agendamentos;host=phpmyadmin.srv-45-34-12-242.hostoo.io";
$usuario = "agendamento";
$pass    = "####";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($host, $usuario, $pass);
}catch (PDOExecption $e){
    echo "Falha: ". $e->getMessage();
}

$consulta="select email from clientes where id=103";
$buscaemail = $pdo->query($consulta)->fetchColumn();

$email    = "$buscaemail";
$assunto  = "Email Teste";
$mensagem = "teste de email enviado com php e sql";
$header   = "from: victor teste";

mail($email, $assunto, $mensagem, $header);

?>
```